# Random number generation speed

Tags: php, javascript, random

Quick question, has anyone done a benchmark on random number generation between javascript and php? I'm not talking about 4-5 random function calls but on a large scale, I'm more interested about speed rather than better random numbers.

Comment: Why worry about a few mathematical operations when the you can get better performance when looking at the bigger picture?!

Comment: Also keep in mind that Javascript nowadays is orders of magnitude faster than PHP due to advances in JIT compiling techniques used for Javascript while PHP is still interpreted.

Comment: @Ed Heal I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Your best bet would be to test node.js vs php.

Comment: @Joey: PHP5 was released a long time ago, and with it came the Zend engine, which actually compiles PHP into bytecode (similar to the way java is compiled). Not an interpreted language, but a compiled language. Functions like `compiler_halt()` and packages like bcompiler and HiPHoP should be seen as clues

Comment: Less than 1/10 of a second for 100000 random numbers generated in PHP ([see here](http://codepad.org/9zRB740o)) - somehow I suspect the *speed* of the number generation is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Less than 1/50 of a second over at [viper-7](http://codepad.viper-7.com/x690hf)

Comment: Generating a random number takes a few mathematical operations. Accessing the network or hard disc is **A LOT** more expensive. If you want to improve performance of your software find out who is the big hitters. It will not be on the generation of random numbers for a start.

Comment: Elias: Hiphop compiles PHP to C++; that's a completely different beast. And if they really do the same as Java, .NET, JS do then they did a very, very crappy job.

Comment: there are 2 major random engines for php, rand and mt_rand (x4 faster); but your question is more of a hardware.

Comment: While I still maintain it doesn't really matter, identical [Javascript](http://pastebin.com/xUqf730r) and [PHP](http://pastebin.com/BUEZUn7f) code, when run on Node.js/PHP 5.4.3 on a WinXP SP3 x86 laptop, Javascript is around 8 times faster than PHP - for 10000000 iterations Javascript = 0.362 secs, PHP = 2.931 secs.

Comment: @Joey: I know what HipHop does, and I'm not for a moment suggesting that that's the standard proceedings for all PHP scripts. But the zend engine does compile all scripts to zend bytecode at runtime, that runs on the Zend Engine (which is, in essence, a virtual machine). Code, compiled to bytecode that runs from a virtual machine... sounds Java-like to me

Comment: Java uses a JIT compiler where essentially machine code is run. The days of interpreted bytecode are long over, except for many scripting languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alan pointed out, the performance of JavaScript's random numbers depends on the resources the client-side brings to the party. However, there are a few more things to consider:
Since you're looking for random numbers, generated on a large scale, it is important to note that browsers may stop your JavaScript from reaching the end of a loop. Some browsers might assume the script contains a deadlock somewhere and ask the user to stop or debug the script. 
In addition to this, the numbers will only be generated as long as the client is on the page *and* has JavaScript enabled.

On PHP, there are two things to consider (apart from server hardware). If you're really planning on generating vast quantities of random numbers, the response to your client will be slowed down, too. Though PHP is faster then JavaScript (by far), it's no good to have your visitors wait too long for a response from the server. 
A possible solution might be to send the response out anyway and get the randomly generated numbers via ajax. Downside here is: you've lost the speed benefit of php.

In your situation, I'd keep the random generator server side. Perhaps look into other languages to put together a little C programme if you're really focused on speed and server load (PHP is resource expensive). But sticking to the tags, again: stick to php - after all, quite a lot of it is C anyways...

Answer (score 1):

This will greatly depend on your hardware and environment.  In Javascript, different browsers will run at different speeds for example.

The best bet is to write a loop in each and run it to generate a large number of random numbers and show you how long it took.  That way you will know which runs better for your particular setup.

Comment: If it is that much browser dependent then I might have to do it server side, all kinds of users will use it.